# Quick Documentation For Scala Apply Constructor Pattern in IntelliJ IDE

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, documentation, apply, intellij-plugin

I am wondering if there is a way to get the quick documentation in IntelliJ to work for the class construction pattern many scala developers use below.

`SomeClass(Param1,Parma2)`

instead of

`new SomeClass(param1,Param2)`

The direct constructor call made with new obviously works but many scala devs use apply to construct objects.  When that pattern is used the Intelij documentation look up fails to find any information on the class.

Comment: I think you are referring to case-classes?

Comment: @ShankarShastri I have edited my question to be more clear.  Perhaps some people reading my question had never used the documentation features in intelij.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there are documents in IntelliJ per se.  However, the pattern is fairly easy to explain.

There's a pattern in Java code for having static factory methods (this is a specialization of the Gang of Four Factory Method Pattern), often along the lines of (translated to Scala-ish):

```
object Foo {
  def barInstance(args...): Bar = ???
}
```

The main benefit of doing this is that the factory controls object instantiation, in particular:

- the particular runtime class to instantiate, possibly based on the arguments to the factory.  For example, the generic immutable collections in Scala have factory methods which may create optimized small collections if they're created with a sufficiently small amount of contents.  An example of this is a sequence of length 1 can be implemented with basically no overhead with a single field referring to the object and a lookup that checks if the offset is 0 and either throws or returns its sole field.
- whether an instance is created.  One can cache arguments to the factory and memoize or "hashcons" the created objects, or precreate the most common instances and hand them out repeatedly.

A further benefit is that the factory is a function, while `new` is an operator, which allows the factory to be passed around:

```
class Foo(x: Int)

object Foo {
  def instance(x: Int) = new Foo(x)
}

Seq(1, 2, 3).map(x => Foo(x))  // results in Seq(Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3))
```

In Scala, this is combined with the fact that the language allows any object which defines an `apply` method to be used syntactically as a function (even if it doesn't extend `Function`, which would allow the object to be passed around as if it's a function) and with the "companion object" to a class (which incorporates the things that in Java would be `static` in the class) to get something like:

```
class Foo(constructor_args...)

object Foo {
  def apply(args...): Foo = ???
}
```

Which can be used like:

```
Foo(...)
```

For a `case class`, the Scala compiler automatically generates a companion object with certain behaviors, one of which is an `apply` with the same arguments as the constructor (other behaviors include contract-obeying `hashCode` and `equals` as well as an `unapply` method to allow for pattern matching).

Comment: There is a feature in intelij called "Quick Documentation" (ctr j in osx).  It allows you to see params for an object and other documentation.  It currently does not work with the factory pattern that commonly is implemented with scalas apply method.  That is what this question is about.